# Is it possible to add UI test target with default test class programatically in Xcode?

Tags: import, automated-tests, addition, setup-project, xcuitest

Upon creating a UI target to the app two files will be created in Xcode.

> **MyAppUITests.swift** and **info.plist**

These both files are placed under the **MyAppUITests** folder.

The swift class has some default test methods to starts with whereas the plist has the settings info of the created UI test. We are then write test cases, write some utility classes etc. The utility classes also saved under the UI test target. The whole setup works fine with "MyApp".

**Requirement**: I want to give this setup to some other tester/developer who is a newbie. Means, if they want to implement the UI testing in their app, I want to give them a sample setup which will contain the UI test target with some sample test cases and utility methods.

**Current flow:** Currently we are having documents regarding the UI test setup, the usage of the written utilities, etc. A person can read those documents and do all the steps manually to setup the UI test environment.

We want to take it to the next level by automate this setup process. Something like, if I keep the sample files in a repo and create a run script that can import the files from repo and add it to the newbie's source code while running. I'm not sure this is possible and I appreciate the suggestions on it.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do the generic preparation by yourself. Then, with the help of `git` write a bash script that does this preparation. I suppose you can automate some of the most difficult to automate steps with `xcodeproj` generators like

https://github.com/yonaskolb/XcodeGen